# error while executing mysqli fetch

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've a php, which displays rows from a MySQL DB, sql query is like this

```
$cat = 'Available'
$sql = "SELECT title, location, date, matter, userName, emailId, phone FROM ad_usr WHERE type =".$cat;
```

query works fine in mysql.

but when try to execute following codes

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

gives an error like this

> "mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean
>   given"

but when I use `$cat` serialNo instead of type and `$cat` as an integer then it works fine

Comment: We get hundreds of questions like this every day. You'll soon get half a dozen answers spotting the syntax error. Please don't just copy the correct code and go on—learn how to do error checking yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed to close the `"`

```
 $sql = "SELECT title, location, date, matter, userName, emailId, phone FROM ad_usr WHERE type ='$cat'";
```

You can able to find these errors yourself, if you use editor like `eclipse` and etc

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
$cat = "Available";
$sql = "SELECT title, location, date, matter, userName, emailId, phone FROM ad_usr WHERE type ='$cat'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to guess. The [Quick Start Guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php) has several usage examples. Please have a look at [Executing statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php); most examples listed there show how to do error checking.